# What is the scope of global variables inside C++ DLLs

Tags: c++, windows, dll, global-variables

Let's say a 3rd-party DLL **X** has a global variable **G**

I write two separate DLLs (as plugins for an app) **P1** & **P2** which both dynamically load **X**.

The application's process loads my two plugins **P1** & **P2** so both are loaded at the same time.

Does this mean I have one instance of **G** or two?

**edit:**

The usage scenario is **X** is a 3D rendering engine which has singletons wrapping system resources, it is simply not designed to expect multiple instances in a process - you can run 2 **X**-based apps at once but trying to initialize **X** twice in the *same* app will mess up.
The plugins are both using **X** but would be deployed as separate installers, they would *not* know about each other and would not share the same **X**.dll file - typicall each plugin would have its own dir for storing required resources and DLLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DLL loading routines exposed in the Win32 API make sure you only have one copy of a DLL loaded per process ([see the "Remarks" section here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx), particular paragraph three and the last paragraph before the Security Remarks section, where per-process reference counts are discussed). I assume you're just calling `LoadLibrary` or similar, in which case you have one instance of G.

It appears as thought it *is* possible to circumvent this by having multiple copies of the DLL in question in different locations ([as noted in this sort-of related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587176/load-multiple-copies-of-dll-in-same-process)), and loading each of those, in which case you could end up with multiple copies of all of the data in each DLL (G included).

Comment: So does this mean if **P1** & **P2** are both _statically_ linked to **X**.lib instead, now the "problem" goes away?

Comment: @John What problem? Do you want to have two instances of G?

Comment: @David Heffernan more that I want to avoid not knowing if a DLL has global vars, which could cause weird bugs. See my comment on your answer.

Comment: To check I've understood... if I am writing **P1** & **P2** as plugins for app **A** and each is installed with it's own sub-dir App\plugins\<pluginName> containing additional DLLs & resources. Now each plugin would tend to ship with its own copy of **X** anyway, so it seems there would be two copies of **G** automatically in this case?

Comment: If each plugin loaded X.dll from it's own directory, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is a single instance of global variable in each process.  It's all explained at MSDN: [Dynamic-Link Library Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682594%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This might warrant a new question(?) but _can_ you load a DLL in a new process in some way to force a 'unique' copy of it? If some 3rd-party DLL uses global vars, mightn't you want to have a way to avoid this issue?

Comment: @John You can do so. You need to create a temporary copy of it so that it has a different filename, then you'll get two instances of G. It's pretty non-standard though. You should probably come up with a cleaner way of doing this by allocating the variable on the heap.

Comment: If you load your dll into a new process you have two instances of your variable. One for each process.

Comment: @John You need to describe what your concern is here, in more detail. There's nothing automatically wrong with the use of global variables. They can be used safely in some circumstances.

Comment: @frast No, John is concerned about what happens inside a single process.

Comment: @David Ok I did not see that. In a single process you can only do the rename trick as you already mentioned.

Comment: @John You'll need to get copies of **X**.dll in separate file locations. How to do this will depend on how the plugin modules load X.