# Using AppDomains to Parallelize Non-thread-safe DLL

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, parallel-processing, appdomain

I have an unmanaged C++ DLL that my .NET application uses via p/invoke.  The method that I need from this DLL is fairly time consuming and I would like to parallelize the method calls.  The problem is that it uses a bunch of statics and globals, so it is not thread-safe (and can't be changed).  My plan was to overcome this non-thread-safe issue by calling the unmanaged DLL from multiple AppDomains in parallel.

I can call the unmanaged code from the multiple AppDomains without any problems as long as I don't do it in parallel, but as soon as I make the calls in parallel, I get an `AccessViolationException`.  I am using Parallel.For() to make the parallel calls.

Is it possible to make a non-thread-safe unmanaged DLL "thread-safe" by simply making the calls from multiple AppDomains?

Comment: For unmanaged DLLs that don't play well with multithreading, process isolation is IMHO *much* easier than appdomains.

Answer (score 7):

Calling the native method from multiple `AppDomain` instances won't help you at all here.  `AppDomain` boundaries don't apply to native DLL's and they won't provide any benefit

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost: [Load multiple copies of dll in same process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587176/load-multiple-copies-of-dll-in-same-process)

You'd have to make sure that all invocations within an AppDomain are on a single thread.

ParallelFor cannot make that happen, so you'd need to

- manually parallelize (chunk up your loop for each thread/appdomain)
- better (IMHO): write a wrapper function that will use a specific instance of your native dll (e.g. by using a reference to the AppDomain from threadlocal storage?).

Note that depending on the complexity of your situation (callbacks, use of global data in managed library) you might want to limit execution of each AppDomain to a specific CPU core (core affinity: see [`Begin/EndThreadAffinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx)). I might be a tad paranoid here :)

Comment: This is an interesting idea that I will try.  So, if I load multiple copies of the same DLL, why does each instance need to be called from the same thread?

Comment: Like I said it was (bordering on) paranoia. Technically code might depend on CPU-local caches; I'd need to re-read some docs here as my memory of it in relation to context switches is quite hazy right now. Suffice it to say, in such circumstances, I'd expect the native DLL to manage it's own thread affinity, really because this problem isn't really limited to using from within a .NET application at all). So: don't worry :)

Comment: Since this native DLL (native.dll) uses global and static variables, will multiple copies of these variables be created in memory when I load native1.dll, native2.dll, native3.dll, etc. so I can use them in parallel?

Comment: @dewald: yes. That is, normally. All dynamic allocations are... dynamic anyway, and the datasegment is copied by virtue of the fact that you are loading actual copies of the image. The only thing that could trip you up is the use of named pipes, shared memory maps, and interprocess synchronisation primitives; You can see what is being used with e.g. [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) or [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655). Be sure to work out what your own app uses for contrast

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the C++ DLL in an EXE and parallelize process invocations (instead of running this code in threads or AppDomains). I had this problem with GeckoFX, which doesn't like threads, and this solution worked just fine. Of course, it's up to you to manage communication with these processes. I [blogged about this](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/03/proxying-and-parallelizing-processes.html) some time ago.