# Matlab Mex library lifecycle

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

Does anyone know what the matlab mex library lifecycle is?  Specifically I am interested in the following:

1. Is there a way to force the library to be loaded before invoking it?
2. Is the library a singleton or are multiple instances loaded?
3. Are there any hooks for initialization prior to invocation?
4. Is there a destructor hook/signal that can be intercepted when the library is unloaded for cleanup?

I did an extensive search here and online and I could not find the answers to these questions.  My problem has some performance cost with initialization and I would like to avoid that if possible, without needing to write a service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, in Windows you could implement [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx) entry point. This is because MEX-file are just regular DLL files with different extension. Here is a minimal example:

#### testDLL.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        mexPrintf("DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: hModule=0x%x\n", hModule);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        mexPrintf("DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: hModule=0x%x\n", hModule);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mexPrintf("Inside MEX-function\n");
}
```

Here is how it works:

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims testDLL.cpp

>> testDLL
DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: hModule=0xa0980000
Inside MEX-function

>> testDLL
Inside MEX-function

>> clear testDLL
DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: hModule=0xa0980000
```

Comment: For Linux, you could probably use global/static C++ objects to achieve something similar. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463718/linux-equivalent-of-dllmain

Comment: Great example, now linked from my answer. +1

Comment: This is a great answer thank you!  I am on Linux, but I can implement a c++ class with a static constructor as pointed out by Amro.  Also chappj thanks a lot for the detailed information and examples.  I don't know why the system won't let me pick two correct answers.

Comment: @panos No problem, Amro is the real MEX expert. Thanks for the upvote though. Anyway, my example should work in Linux if you remove the `#include <windows.h>` and replace `NULL` with `(void*)`, although the `mexAtExit` function you register with MATLAB is not as flexible as `DllMain` or a static class constructor & destructor.

Comment: I should say that in general, you ought to be [very careful](http://blog.barthe.ph/2009/07/30/no-stdlib-in-dllmai/) about what you put inside your DllMain function: https://www.google.com/search?q=DllMain+site:blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing

Answer (score 9):

A MEX file stays loaded until you clear it (`clear myMexFun` or `clear mex`) or quit MATLAB.

For pre-loading, all I can suggest is to call the function with no inputs or with nop-equivalent inputs. I have created simple code paths in my `mexFunction`s to handle such calls without error, the simplest example being `if(!nrhs) return;`. Subsequent calls will not need to load the `mexFunction` from disk (or any other functions in shared libraries called by the MEX function) and you do not need to worry about initialization cost after that.

Regarding initialization/cleanup, constructors/destructors, etc. I am not aware of any way to see *what MATLAB is doing* when loading or unloading the MEX file, but a MEX file is a regular shared library (i.e. DLL/SO) that just exports a single function ([`mexFunction` is the only entry point](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html)), so, as Amro points out, you can implement a `DllMain` in Windows to define module and thread attach/detach operations (see the excellent example in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20577537/2778484)). I'm not aware of any other mechanisms for interacting with the library.

To perform tasks when the module unloads, you can use [`mexAtExit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexatexit.html) within `mexFunction` to register with MATLAB a function to call when the MEX function unloads (again, cleared or MATLAB exits). Simply define a `static` function in the global namespace and register it with `mexAtExit`. The example provided by MATLAB (mexatexit.c) demonstrates closing a file stream that was opened within `mexFunction`, but not closed. You could also free persistent memory, close streams, etc. Here is a contrived example:

**mexDLLtext.cpp**:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static FILE   *fp=NULL;
static double *pDataC=NULL, *pDataCpp=NULL, *pMxData=NULL;
static char fName[L_tmpnam], counter = 0;

static void CleanUp(void)
{
  fclose(fp);        /* close file opened with fopen */
  free(pDataC);      /* deallocate buffer allocated with malloc/calloc */
  delete[] pDataCpp; /* deallocate buffer allocated with new double[...] */
  mxFree(pMxData);   /* free data created with mx function like mxMalloc */

  mexPrintf("Closing %s and freeing memory...\n",fName);
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    if (!fp) { tmpnam(fName); fp = fopen(fName,"w"); }
    fprintf(fp,"%d ",++counter);

    if (!pDataC) pDataC = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*16);
    if (!pDataCpp) pDataCpp = new double[16];
    if (!pMxData) {
        pMxData = (double*) mxMalloc(sizeof(double)*16);
        mexMakeMemoryPersistent(pMxData); mexPrintf("First!\n");
    }

    mexAtExit(CleanUp);
    // Then use the persistent data...
}
```

When run:

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims mexDLLtest.cpp
>> for i=1:5, mexDLLtest; end
First!
>> clear mexDLLtest
Closing \s1rg.1 and freeing memory...
>> type E:\s1rg.1

1 2 3 4 5
```

And you have some control over unloading of the file via [`mexLock`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexlock.html) and [`mexUnlock`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexunlock.html).

What happens to the arguments (i.e. `prhs`, `plhs`) when the function starts and returns to MATLAB is [very well documented](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/c-c-source-mex-files.html), on the other hand, so I guess that's not what you are asking about.

Regarding multiple instances, you could try using [Sysinternals' Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (if using Window) to have a look at what loaded modules have threads running under MATLAB.exe. I only ever see *one instance* of a (single threaded) MEX file in threads list no matter how many times or how fast I call the function. However, once back at the command line, you can do `version -modules` to see a list of loaded modules, as Amro suggested. The MEX file will still be there, and as with the list of threads visible by Process Explorer, I only ever see one instance of a MEX certain file.

Thanks, Amro for the input. I'm interested to see even some more authoritative answers to these questions!

Comment: In Windows, MEX-files are really just DLL files with a .mexw32/.mexw64 extension. So you should be able to write the regular [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx) entry function, and handle `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`,.. notifications. Plus MATLAB provides a documented way to register an exit function: [`mexAtExit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexatexit.html). BTW you can use `version -modules` to see a list of all loaded modules instead of using Sysinternals tool.

Comment: As for managing the lifecycle of a MEX-function, I find that implementing a *switchyard* pattern is a good technique (have the function receive a 'string' as an argument which determine what action to perform, like new/delete/get/set/etc..). You could even make the MEX-function "private" (by placing it inside a `private` folder) and expose its functionality through a MATLAB OOP class, this will give u proper constructor/destructor semantics, especially useful when the MEX file wraps a C++ class (see the [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv) project for an example of this pattern).

Comment: @Amro Thanks for the input. I forgot about `mexAtExit`. That's pretty relevant, so I added a bit about it, and I've generally improved my answer considering your comments. Great idea about DllMain. I linked to your answer.

Comment: thanks, nice example using `mexAtExit`/`mexMakeMemoryPersistent` +1. btw you are right in that there is only one instance of the MEX module loaded at any time (that would defeat the whole purpose of **shared** libraries otherwise). Not to mention that the entire MX/MEX APIs are [not thread-safe](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101658). Even if it were [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1587451/97160), loading multiple copies of the same MEX-function executed in simultaneous threads (inside the same process) would open up a whole new can of worms :)