# How to recompile model DLL without restarting MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am in the process of developing an SFunction and compiled submodel in Simulink, an SFunction that calls into a DLL compiled using Realtime Workshop. The problem is, once I compile the submodel once, execute it in native Simulink through the SFunction and the model finishes, MATLAB still keeps a handle to the submodel DLL. I cannot recompile the DLL until MATLAB is restarted, forcing the release of the DLL.

I have even gone so far as to see if ProcessExplorer could force closed the handle but it can't.

Comment: Have you tried closing the model? Does it make a difference? Also, have you tried `clear functions` after closing the model? It should clear all MEX functions from memory.

Comment: Have tried:

(1) clear <model_name>, (2) clear mex, (3) clear all, (4) bdclose all, (5) unloadlibrary(<dll_name>), (6) closing the model, (7) closing all models; (8) using SysInternals ProcessExplorer to close the handle; (9) using Unlocker to unlock/delete the DLL and (10) calling FreeLibrary() at the end of the SFunction. None of these seem to influence the problem.

Comment: :-( More than I would have tried... Sorry, don't have any other idea.

Comment: What does `islibloaded('LIBNAME')` return?

Comment: How do you load/call into your dll? Do you unload it after you are done in your mdlTerminate function?

Comment: @Florian, it returns zero.

Comment: @Navan I call FreeLibrary() on the DLL. The first time I tried it it caused a segmentation violation though am having limited success with it now.

Comment: Depending on your settings mdlTerminate sometimes may get called without the full propagation. Make sure you check for valid value before calling FreeLibrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you bind the S-Function to the DLL? If you bind at link time then you could try to [bind at runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Explicit_run-time_linking) and explicitly release the handle in `mdlTerminate`. That way, MATLAB should never even know that you accessed the DLL. Of course this makes the actual interaction with the DLL from within the S-Function somewhat messier.

Comment: This is as close to an answer I have come to so far, using LoadLibrary() and FreeLibrary() being called on mdlStart and mdlTerminate respectively. The first attempt to use it caused a segmentation violation so am a bit nervous, but it has worked somewhat since then.

Comment: @JCollins: Just make sure to keep your S-Function reentrant by storing the DLL handle inside a work vector (instead of using a global variable). Then you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would work if you just rename the actual `DLL` to something else and then recompile. I know it works for `mex` files. If this doesn't work, you can try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575957/matlab-mex-library-lifecycle).

Comment: Renaming is disallowed by Windows because MATLAB.exe has a DLL handle to it.